# Changing WordPress backend layout (removing certain tabs)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

Currently, if any user (besides an admin) logs into `WordPress` backend, it shows them the following tabs:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is to:

1. Remove the `dashboard` tab
2. Remove the `profile` tab
3. Open up the `WooCommerce orders` tab by default (so it shows immediately when the user logs in).

Essentially, something like this:

[image]

To do this, I've tried the following:

```html
function remove_profile_menu() {
  if ( !is_admin() ) {
    remove_submenu_page(‘users.php’, ‘profile.php’);
    remove_menu_page(‘profile.php’);
  }
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_profile_menu');

function remove_dashboard_menu() {
  if ( !is_admin() ) {
    remove_submenu_page(dashbourd.php’);
    remove_menu_page(dashboard.php’);
  }
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_dashboard_menu');
```

But the above does nothing when ran?

Comment: _"Currently, if any user (besides an admin) logs into WordPress backend, it shows them the following tabs:"_ This is not default behavior and is therefore obtained via custom code and/or a plugin. Can you clarify this? You make no mention of this in your question. 
You also have a typo in your code "dashbourd". Regards

Comment: Besides @7uc1f3r answer, I would either suggest creating a custom role which will be added to a user to manage the hide/show of pages or content. Would be cleaner in my eyes.

Comment: @7uc1f3r - To clarify, are you saying that showing the `dashboard` and `profile` by default is not default behaviour? The only plugin I have active related to roles is https://wordpress.org/plugins/capability-manager-enhanced/. But, this plugin doesn't offer anything in terms of what tabs to show on that users admin

Answer (score 0):

Your given code have several problems.

1. Syntax errors.
2. Wrong function - is_admin is for checking whether the current page belongs to wp-admin. I guess you wanted to check "is current user admin" - for that purpose you should use current_user_can function.

Here is working code for your case:

```
function remove_dashboard_menu() {
  if (!current_user_can('administrator') ) {
    remove_menu_page('index.php');
    remove_menu_page('users.php');
  }
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_dashboard_menu');
```